# how to sum up elements in list of lists for arbitrary combination in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have a list like this,

```
 A =      [[0.8922063, 0.26672425],
          [0.34475611, 0.35976697],
          [0.33253499, 0.18923898],
          [0.66872466, 0.46248986],
          [0.72823733, 0.10537784],
          [0.40903598, 0.70639412],
          [0.79926596, 0.90095583],
          [0.67886544, 0.84573289],
          [0.3641813, 0.64296743],
          [0.07461196, 0.74290527]]
```

which is the combination of lists of list

and I have another list

```
p = [5,4,2]
```

I need to sum up elements of list A corresponding to P, i.e, the sum of the first 5 sub-list of A, then the sum of the next 4 (6th to 9th) sub-list and finally the sum of the last 2 sub-list.

Comment: What is the sum of a sublist?

Comment: @GauravLuitel What's the expected output?

Comment: But what is the result of that. a big list, a tuple of number, a single number?

Comment: Do you need to be able to sum list A given any arbitrary list p?

Comment: Do you mean element-wise sums?

Comment: result should be list of number

Comment: Use the values in `P` to create slices of `A`. Then sum each slice.

Comment: So you want to add the elements in the sublists, then sum those numbers?

Comment: Also in your example A has 10 lists, but p adds up to 11 sub-lists?

Comment: it is [5,4,1], my mistake.

Comment: @0x263A Do you need to be able to sum list A given any arbitrary list p? exactly this is my question. and the result should be list of tuples

Answer (score 0):

Transform your list `p` into a list of the slices you want:

```
>>> q = [0,5,9,10]
```

You can do that this way:

```
>>> q = [sum(p[:i]) for i in range(len(p)+1)]
```

Then sum the slices of `A`:

```
>>> for i in range(len(q)-1):
        listn = sum(sum(x) for x in A[q[i]:q[i+1]])
        print(listn)

4.35005729
5.34739895
0.81751723
```

Answer (score 0):

This function returns a list of sums from chunks in A by keeping track of our last sliced element (starting at 0) and incrementing the index to slice with the numbers in p.

```
def sum_sublists(list1 : list, list2 : list) -> list:
    sums=[]
    last_slice = 0
    for chunk_size in list2:
        next_slice = last_slice+chunk_size
        sums.append(sum([sum(el) for el in list1[last_slice:next_slice]]))
        last_slice = next_slice
    return sums

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = [5,4,1]
    A = [[0.8922063, 0.26672425],
        [0.34475611, 0.35976697],
        [0.33253499, 0.18923898],
        [0.66872466, 0.46248986],
        [0.72823733, 0.10537784],

        [0.40903598, 0.70639412],
        [0.79926596, 0.90095583],
        [0.67886544, 0.84573289],
        [0.3641813, 0.64296743],
        
        [0.07461196, 0.74290527],   
        ]

    print(sum_sublists(A, p))
```